# Coloring HTML <area> based on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function eating(Num) {
  console.log("entered eating", Num);
  
  bodyEating = Num;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < Num; i++) {
    BODYEATING[0].background = "black";
  }
  console.log(BODYEATING[0]);
  //e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/unique-rectangles-formed-using-n-unit-squares.png" usemap="#image-map">
  <map id="map" name="image-map">
    <area target="_self" alt="1" title="1" onclick="eating(1)" coords="21,385,24,309,100,309,101,385" shape="poly">
    <area target="_self" alt="2" title="2" onclick="eating(2)" coords="102,305,23,304,23,228,101,227" shape="poly">
    <area target="_self" alt="3" title="3" onclick="eating(3)" coords="103,225,26,228,25,149,99,151" shape="poly">
    <area target="_self" alt="4" title="4" onclick="eating(4)" coords="103,147,102,65,25,70,23,147" shape="poly">
  </map>
</div>
```

I have something like 5 images, each image is a pile of 10 squares. I want for each image when the user clicks, for example, the image on square 3, then, I will get in my code that the user clicked on square 3 and, also, the squares from 1 to 3 will have a background-color applied.

I did the first goal by making an image map. However, I can't make the coloring goal and I've searched a lot for it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi, Heba. Do you have any relevant code you could post?

Comment: also add a drawing of the intended layout. I have no idea what you mean with: `a pile of 10 squares`, `squares from 1 -3`

Comment: I added the html and javascript files

Comment: I want to color the squares. For example, when I click on square 3,I want to color square 1,2and 3

Comment: Are the images always squares? If so, it would be easier to do this with plain, positioned HTML elements, or SVG elements, or a Canvas element.

Comment: how is that. Can you explain more?

Comment: It is not always squares. I will need to work with polygon shapes also

Comment: I tried changing the image to a transparent one but also the coloring wasn't applied

Comment: Image map <area>s don't really have a visual presence, so they can't be colored. I would suggest making your images SVGs; SVG shapes such as squares and polygons can be trivially recolored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative using an in-line SVG with an image background and polygon elements in the front. The `handleSVGClick` handler is on the SVG element itself to make things easier to manage with less repetition.

```js
function handleSVGClick(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === "polygon") {
    event.target.style.fill = `hsl(${Math.random() * 360}, 90%, 60%)`;
  }
}
```

```css
polygon {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #333;
  fill: transparent;
}
```

```html
<svg width="564" height="409" onclick="handleSVGClick(event)">
  <image
    href="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/unique-rectangles-formed-using-n-unit-squares.png"
    width="564"
    height="409"
  />
  <polygon title="1" points="21,385 24,309 100,309 101,385" />
  <polygon title="2" points="102,305 23,304 23,228 101,227" />
  <polygon title="3" points="103,225 26,228 25,149 99,151" />
  <polygon title="4" points="103,147 102,65 25,70 23,147" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how did you mark each square?

Comment: <polygon title="1" points="21,385 24,309 100,309 101,385" />  this part

Comment: Also the math you did here  `hsl(${Math.random() * 360}, 90%, 60%)` is it to just generate random color or it has other usage?

Comment: It's just for pretty colors, yes. You can find the docs for SVG polygons over at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon

Comment: Is there is a way to determine which polygon I clicked on?

Comment: I  get event.target,.tagName="image

Comment: You can give each polygon an id. The polygons also need to be filled with a transparent color as in my example to be clickable. Otherwise you'll end up clicking through to the image.

Comment: When I add more than one polygon to the image the first one only appears why?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's impossible to quite know why.

Comment: From where did you get this number ="points="21,385 24,309 100,309 101,385"" I know what it means but how did you get it is there a tool or something?

Comment: for example in the same code you wrote earlier, if those were the coordinates only two polygons appear         <polygon title="1" points="24,68,98,68,99,144,23,144" />
        <polygon title="2" points="98,150,25,150,24,222,101,225" />
        <polygon title="3" points="103,225 26,228 25,149 99,151" />
        <polygon title="4" points="103,147 102,65 25,70 23,147" />

Comment: Those are the same coordinates you have, only with a space between each pair of x/y (ie x,y,x,y,x,y is x,y x,y x,y)

Comment: How can I make the polygon shape more smooth looking? especially when I have more curvy shapes like a banana for example

Comment: yes, but this makes it still has sharp edge. Is there is a way to make it look smooth. If a shape has part of it curved, I don't want the curved part to be full of edges. Is there is a way to do that?

Comment: You can use a <path> element in that case. They can describe curves too.

Comment: When I did polygons I used online image map generator to determine the coordinates of a polygon on the image I have. What can I use to determine a path on the image I have?

Comment: You can use e. g. Inkscape, an SVG editor, to draw paths/polygons on top of your image. You can then save the SVG and open it in a text editor to extract the path you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size/position will be static, you can manually position the `map` element and size each `area` to match:

```js
function eating(Num) {
  const squares = document.querySelectorAll('area');

  console.log("entered eating", Num);

  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    if (i < Num) {
      squares[i].style.background = "black";
    } else {
      squares[i].style.background = "transparent";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

map {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 68px;
  left: 22.5px;
}

area {
  width: 79px;
  height: 79px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/unique-rectangles-formed-using-n-unit-squares.png" usemap="#image-map">
  <map id="map" name="image-map">
    <area target="_self" alt="1" title="1" onclick="eating(1)" coords="21,385,24,309,100,309,101,385" shape="poly">
    <area target="_self" alt="2" title="2" onclick="eating(2)" coords="102,305,23,304,23,228,101,227" shape="poly">
    <area target="_self" alt="3" title="3" onclick="eating(3)" coords="103,225,26,228,25,149,99,151" shape="poly">
    <area target="_self" alt="4" title="4" onclick="eating(4)" coords="103,147,102,65,25,70,23,147" shape="poly">
  </map>
</div>
```

However, I wouldn't recommend this method as it isn't scalable, reusable or, in my opinion, best practice.

Comment: I don't understand what this will exactly solve? My problem is I can't color the pile of squares. However, They are clickable and I can get in my code on which square did the user click

Comment: This colors them, click on any square in the left side column and they will have a background-color applied.

Comment: Here, for example if I clicked on square 3, the squares from 1 to 3 are colored balck. Is there is a way to make that if the user clicked again on 2 then the squares from 1to2 only are colored?

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you. However, when I apply this code on polygons it doesn't work. It colors squares? Can you help?

Comment: I want it to color exactly the area that I have in the image map no matter what shape it is?

Comment: Like I said, this solution isn't scalable and using it with other shapes would either be very difficult or impossible. As @AKX said in the comments, you'd be better off with a different approach altogether.

Comment: What are other solutions do you recommend?

Comment: Personally, I'd go with individual `<svg>` elements, but, that's just my preference.

Answer (score 0):

Well in order to have the area clickable they need to have an href attribute. (at least in Firefox).
Since they are hidden it is tough to style them cross browser.
So I went another way and created elements on the same position as the areas and style those when ever the area is clicked.

Those overlays are just a proof of concept, but since I am working with percentages here this could work even if the image is scaled down.

Also I'd recommend doing all of this when Javascript is definitely supported, and also suggest removing the area element if you do not want users to reclick on them a second time.
let me know if there is anything more you would like me to fine tune here:

```js
function eating(Num) {
  console.log("entered eating", Num);    
  if(Num == 4) { // testcode
     document.querySelector("#overlay"+Num).style.display = "block";  
  }
  // remove area from map
 
}
(function init() {
    var container = document.querySelector('.container');
    container.classList.add("js")
})()
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%; 
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block; /* container same width as image */
  width: auto;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}

.container.js {
  position: relative;
}
.container.js .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16.8%; left: 4.3%;
  width: 13.5%; height: 18.5%;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <span class="overlay" id="overlay4"></span>
  <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/unique-rectangles-formed-using-n-unit-squares.png" usemap="#image-map">
  <map id="map" name="image-map">
    <area target="_self" alt="1" title="1" href="#" onclick="eating(1)" coords="21,385,24,309,100,309,101,385" shape="poly">
    <area target="_self" alt="2" title="2" href="#" onclick="eating(2)" coords="102,305,23,304,23,228,101,227" shape="poly">
    <area target="_self" alt="3" title="3" href="#" onclick="eating(3)" coords="103,225,26,228,25,149,99,151" shape="poly">
    <area target="_self" alt="4" title="4" href="#" onclick="eating(4)" coords="103,147,102,65,25,70,23,147" shape="poly">
  </map>
</div>
```